# flattening a dataframe rowwise in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nested, nested-loops, nested-lists

I tried to flatten a small nested dataframe which is given below.

```
>nested dataframe

     A   B    C
0   1   1  [1, 2]
1   2   2  [2, 3]
2   3   3  [3, 4]
```

After flattening the C column I achieved this columnwise.

```
   A   B   C
0   1   1  1
0   1   1  2
1   2   2  2
1   2   2  3
2   3   3  3
2   3   3  4
```

The code I used

```
 dat = pd.DataFrame({'A ': [1,2,3] ,
                        'B ':[1,2,3, ],
                        'C':[[1,2 ], [ 2,3],[ 3,4] ]})
 dataa= dat.explode('C')
```

but what I'm expecting is to obtain something like this row wise.

```
    A   B  C1  C2
0   1   1  1  2
1   2   2  2  3
2   3   3  3  4
```

as I could easily do this in R but in python any help will be appreciated